# is a += a safe for std::string in c++

Tags: c++, stdstring

Is the following code safe in C++

```
std::string a = "foo";
a += a;
```

I suspect the answer is no, but I'm struggling to find any documentation either way on this.

> What's your particular doubt?

The relevant overloaded operator is declared as.

```
string& operator+= (const string& str);
```

My doubt is whether `operator+=` is required to guard against situations where `this` and `str` refer to the same object.

It seems to me that += must perform the following operations.

- Calculate the length of the new string from the size of the two existing strings.
- Re-size the destination buffer (possibly relocating it)
- Copy the characters from the source buffer to the destination buffer.
- Store the new length.

Depending on the precise order in which these operations are performed and whether or not values are cached in local variables, I can see at least two ways this could go wrong.

- A stale pointer could be used for the source of the copy, resulting in a "use after free".
- The new length rather than the old length could be used for the number of characters to copy resulting in a "buffer overflow".

So the question is are implementers required to implement `operator+=` in a manner that is safe when `this and str` refer to the same object.

Comment: What's your particular doubt? I don't see anything ill formed from this code?!?

Comment: I assume you're wondering because [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+=) takes a reference to the right-hand side. And for this case the left-hand side and the right-hand- side is the same object.

Comment: It is safe.  As safe as if you had done `a = a + a;`

Comment: You question asks about `operator +=`, but per [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.op.append), `operator +=` has the same behavior as `append` so I'm closing to the append Q.